# Combine and Propagate "Vectors" in Power Query M

Tags: r, powerquery-m

## Background

In an [earlier post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/288977), I prototyped an M equivalent of [**`tidyselect`**](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org) in R: in particular, its general [syntax](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/language.html) and [selection helpers](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/articles/syntax.html#selection-helpers).  **In *this* post, I prototype a syntactic engine for [combining and propagating](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/articles/syntax.html#name-combination-and-propagation) field names**.

## Challenge

The M language has two "near misses" for imitating a [`vector`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/vector.html) in R: essentially a homogeneous scalar array with a [`names`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/names.html) attribute, which may be nonexistent ([`NULL`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/NULL.html)) and which may have missing (`""`) or duplicate names.  The closest M equivalents are:

1. a [`list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/m-spec-types#list-types), which is heterogeneous and *lacks* names; **or**
2. a [`record`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/m-spec-types#record-types), which is heterogeneous and enforces a *full* set of *unique* names.

Likewise, M has two near misses for the [`c()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/c.html) syntax, which combines vectors and (optionally) their names.

```r
# Nameless vector...
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
x
#> [1] 1 2 3

# ...and its nonexistent names.
names(x)
#> NULL


# Fully named vector...
y <- c(a = 1, b = 2, b = 3)
y
#> a b b 
#> 1 2 3 

# ..and its vector of names.
names(y)
#> [1] "a" "b" "b"


# Mixed vector...
z <- c(1, b = 2, b = 3)
z
#>   b b 
#> 1 2 3 

# ..and its vector of names.
names(z)
#> [1] ""  "b" "b"
```

The closest M equivalents are:

1. [`{...}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/expressions-values-and-let-expression#list), which generates a nameless `list`; **or**
2. [`[a = ...]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/expressions-values-and-let-expression#record), which generates a fully (and uniquely) named `record`.

## Approach

In order to model the desired behavior, I first model the `vector` *itself*.  I give you **"`Vec`tor"**: an M `list` that permits heterogeneous values and represents missing names as [`null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/m-spec-values#null)s, yet otherwise replicates the R `vector`.  Its `[names]` are stored in its [**metadata**](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/metadata) as a `list`.  When working with a `Vec`tor, you may:

- construct it via the `Vec_From*()` family; **and**
- extract its information via `Vec_Names()` and `Vec_HasNames()`; **and**
- manipulate it via `Vec_SetNames()` and `Vec_Unname()`; **and**
- inspect it via `Vec_Keys()`, `Vec_Pairs()`, and `Vec_Table()`.

Harnessing this API, I finally implement **`Vec_Combo()`**, which recursively expands the values while combining and propagating their names.  With this `Vec_*()` arsenal, even the mixed `vector` in R...

```r
# Mixed vector...
z <- c(1, b = 2, b = 3)
z
#>   b b 
#> 1 2 3
```

...may be modeled in M:

```m
z = Vec_Combo({1, [b = 2], [b = 3]}),
output = Vec_Table(z)
```

[image: 15]

## Examples

Here are modeled the motivating use cases.

### Construction

We may construct arbitrarily complex vectors.

| Vector | [`c(...)`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/c.html) Arguments | `Vec_Combo(...)` Argument | M Syntax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Unnamed | `1, 2, 3` | `{1, 2, 3}` | [`{...}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/expressions-values-and-let-expression#list) |
| Fully named | `a = 1, b = 2, d = 3` | `[a = 1, b = 2, d = 3]` | [`[...]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/expressions-values-and-let-expression#record) |
| Mixed | `1, b = 2, d = 3` | `{1, [b = 2, d = 3]}` | Both |
| Duplicated | `a = 1, b = 2, b = 3` | `{[a = 1, b = 2], [b = 3]}` | Both |
| Both | `1, b = 2, b = 3` | `{1, [b = 2], [b = 3]}` | Both |
| Nested | `a = 1, b = c(2, 3)` | `[a = 1, b = {2, 3}]` | Both |
| Nested | `1, c(b = 2, 3))` | `{1, {[b = 2], 3}}` | Both |

### Combination

Combination obeys the following rules:

> When named inputs are provided in ... or [`c()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/c.html), the selection is renamed.  If the inputs are already named, the outer and inner names are **combined** with a `...` separator:
>
> ```
> mtcars %>% select_loc(foo = c(bar = mpg, baz = cyl))
> #> foo...bar foo...baz
> #>         1         2
> ```

Its syntax in R...

```r
foo = c(bar = mpg, baz = cyl)
```

...is modeled like so in M...

```m
[foo = [bar = "mpg", baz = "cyl"]]
```

...to yield the following result:

```m
v = Vec_Combo([foo = [bar = "mpg", baz = "cyl"]], "..."),
//                                                ^^^^^
//                                           Custom separator.
output = Vec_Table(v)
```

[image: 16]

### Propagation

Propagation obeys the following rules:

> Otherwise the outer names is **propagated** to the selected elements according to the following rules:
>
> - With data frames, a numeric suffix is appended because columns must be uniquely named.
>
>   ```
>   mtcars %>% select_loc(foo = c(mpg, cyl))
>   #> foo1 foo2 
>   #>    1    2
>   ```

Its syntax in R...

```r
foo = c(mpg, cyl)
```

...is modeled like so in M...

```m
[foo = {"mpg", "cyl"}]
```

...to yield the following result:

```m
v = Vec_Combo([foo = {"mpg", "cyl"}]),
output = Vec_Table(v)
```

[image: 17]

### Composition

Their composition obeys the following rules.

> Combination and propagation can be composed by using nested [`c()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/c.html):
>
> ```
>   mtcars %>% select_loc(foo = c(bar = c(mpg, cyl)))
>   #> foo...bar1 foo...bar2 
>   #>          1          2
> ```

Its syntax in R...

```r
foo = c(bar = c(mpg, cyl))
```

...is modeled like so in M...

```m
[foo = [bar = {"mpg", "cyl"}]]
```

...to yield the following result:

```m
v = Vec_Combo([foo = [bar = {"mpg", "cyl"}]], "..."),
//                                            ^^^^^
//                                       Custom separator.
output = Vec_Table(v)
```

[image: 18]

---

## API

The functions exposed to the user.

### `Vec_Combo()`

This **engine** combines a `list` of structures into a single "`Vec`tor": scalars, `list`s, `record`s, and even other vectors.

It is the analog to [`c()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/c.html) in R: **it can singlehandedly generate *any* vector**, with judicious nesting of [`{...}`](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/language.html) and [`[...]`](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/articles/syntax.html#selection-helpers).

```m
let Vec_Combo = (
    vectors as any,
    optional comboSep as nullable text,
    optional propSep as nullable text,
    optional propBase as nullable number
) as nullable list =>
    let
        // Constants.
        DFL_COMBO_SEP = ".",
        DFL_PROP_SEP = "",
        DFL_PROP_BASE = 1,

        // Defaults.
        cmbSep = Value_IfNull(comboSep, DFL_COMBO_SEP),
        prpSep = Value_IfNull(propSep, DFL_PROP_SEP),
        prpBase = Value_IfNull(propBase, DFL_PROP_BASE),
        
        // Workflow.
        result = Vec_Expand(vectors, null, cmbSep, prpSep, prpBase)
    in
        result
in
    Vec_Combo
```

You may format combination via `comboSep` (like `"~"`), and propagation via `propSep` (like `"_"`) and `propBase` (like `0`), to customize the results: `foo~bar_0`, `foo~bar_1`, etc.

### Construction

#### `Vec_FromList()`

Treat a `list` as a vector, with an optional `names` attribute.

```m
let Vec_FromList = (
    values as list,
    optional names as nullable list
) as list =>
    Vec_SetNames(Value.RemoveMetadata(values), names)
in
    Vec_FromList
```

#### `Vec_FromPairs()`

Construct a vector from a `list` of `{name, value}` pairings.

```m
let Vec_FromPairs = (pairs as list) as list =>
    let
        parallel = List.Buffer(List.Zip(pairs)),
        names = parallel{0},
        values = parallel{1},
        result = Vec_FromList(values, names)
    in
        result
in
    Vec_FromPairs
```

#### `Vec_FromRecord()`

Treat a `record` as a vector, by mapping names to values.

```m
let Vec_FromRecord = (record as record) as list =>
    Vec_FromList(
        Record.FieldValues(record),
        Record.FieldNames(record)
    )
in
    Vec_FromRecord
```

### Information

#### `Value_IsVector()`

Check if a `list` is (`true`) a vector.

```m
let Value_IsVector = (value as any) as logical =>
    Value.Is(value, type list) and Vec_HasNames(value)
in
    Value_IsVector
```

#### `Vec_HasNames()`

Check if a vector has (`true`) any `[names]`.

```m
let Vec_HasNames = (vector as list) as logical =>
    Vec_Names(vector) <> null
in
    Vec_HasNames
```

#### `Vec_Names()`

Extract the `[names]` from a vector.

```m
let Vec_Names = (vector as list) as nullable list =>
    Value.Metadata(vector)[names]?
in
    Vec_Names
```

### Manipulation

#### `Vec_SetNames()`

Set the `[names]` for a vector.

```m
let Vec_SetNames = (
    vector as list,
    names as nullable list
) as list =>
    if names = null then
        Value_PokeMetadata(vector, [names = null])
    else
        Value_PokeMetadata(vector, [names = Names_Fill(names, List.Count(vector))])
in
    Vec_SetNames
```

#### `Vec_Unname()`

Remove the `[names]` from a vector.

```m
let Vec_Unname = (vector as list) as list =>
    Vec_SetNames(vector, null)
in
    Vec_Unname
```

### Reformatting

Inspect a vector via a more transparent structure.

#### `Vec_Keys()`

Treat a vector as a `record`, mapping *unique* `[names]` ("keys") to values.

```m
let Vec_Keys = (vector as list) as record =>
    Record.FromList(vector, Vec_FullNames(vector))
in
    Vec_Keys
```

#### `Vec_Pairs()`

Treat a vector as a `list` of `{name, value}` pairings.

```m
let Vec_Pairs = (vector as list) as list =>
    List.Zip({Vec_FullNames(vector), vector})
in
    Vec_Pairs
```

#### `Vec_Table()`

Tabulate a vector in a `table` of the form `Name | Value`.

```m
let Vec_Table = (vector as list) as table =>
    let
        // Constants.
        NAME_COL = "Name",
        VAL_COL = "Value",
        
        // Workflow.
        data = Table.FromColumns({Vec_FullNames(vector), vector}, {NAME_COL, VAL_COL}),
        result = Table.TransformColumnTypes(data, {
            {NAME_COL, type text},
            {VAL_COL,  type any}
        })
    in
        result
in
    Vec_Table
```

## Support

The hidden functions that support the API.

```m
// ############
// ## Naming ##
// ############

// "Percolate" a name through a set: combine or propagate.
let Names_Perc = (
    name as text,
    names as list,
    comboSep as text,
    propSep as text,
    propBase as number
) as list =>
    if List.Contains(names, null) then
        let
            combo = Names_Combo(name, names, comboSep),
            prop = Names_Prop(name, List.Count(names), propSep, propBase),
            clsc = List.Transform(List.Zip({names, combo, prop}), each if _{0} = null then _{2} else _{1})
        in
            clsc
    else
        Names_Combo(name, names, comboSep)
in
    Names_Perc


// Combine a name with a set.
let Names_Combo = (
    name as text,
    names as list,
    sep as text
) as list =>
    List.Transform(names, each name & sep & Value_IfNull(_, ""))
in
    Names_Combo


// Propagate a name into a set.
let Names_Prop = (
    name as text,
    count as number,
    sep as text,
    base as number
) as list =>
    if count = 0 then
        {}
    else if count = 1 then
        {name}
    else
        let
            indices = List.Numbers(base, count, 1),
            result = List.Transform(indices, each name & sep & Text.From(_)) // culture
        in
            result
in
    Names_Prop


// Fill a set with "missing" names: enough to match their vector.
let Names_Fill = (
    names as list,
    count as number
) as list =>
    List.FirstN(List_PadEnd(names, count, null), count)
in
    Names_Fill


// #############
// ## Vectors ##
// #############

// Expand nested values into a "flat" vector, under a "percolated" name.
let Vec_Expand = (
    item as any,
    name as nullable text,
    comboSep as text,
    propSep as text,
    propBase as number
) as nullable list =>
    if item = null then
        Vec_ExpandNul()
    else if Value_IsScalar(item) then
        Vec_ExpandScl(item, name)
    else if Value_IsVector(item) then
        Vec_ExpandVec(item, name, comboSep, propSep, propBase)
    else if Value.Is(item, type list) then
        Vec_ExpandLst(item, name, comboSep, propSep, propBase)
    else if Value.Is(item, type record) then
        Vec_ExpandRcd(item, name, comboSep, propSep, propBase)
    else
        null
in
    Vec_Expand


// Expand a NULL value into nothing.
let Vec_ExpandNul = () as list =>
    Vec_FromList({})
in
    Vec_ExpandNul


// Expand a scalar value into a trivial vector.
let Vec_ExpandScl = (
    scalar as any,
    name as nullable text
) as list =>
    if name = null then
        Vec_FromList({scalar})
    else
        Vec_FromList({scalar}, {name})
in
    Vec_ExpandScl


// Expand a vector.
let Vec_ExpandVec = (
    vector as list,
    name as nullable text,
    comboSep as text,
    propSep as text,
    propBase as number
) as list =>
    let
        pairs = Vec_Pairs(vector),
        vectors = List.Transform(pairs, each Vec_Expand(_{1}, _{0}, comboSep, propSep, propBase)),
        expanded = List.Buffer(Vec_Append(vectors)),
        result = Vec_PercNames(expanded, name, comboSep, propSep, propBase)
    in
        result
in
    Vec_ExpandVec


// Expand a simple list.
let Vec_ExpandLst = (
    list as list,
    name as nullable text,
    comboSep as text,
    propSep as text,
    propBase as number
) as list =>
    Vec_ExpandVec(Vec_FromList(list, null), name, comboSep, propSep, propBase)
in
    Vec_ExpandLst


// Expand a record.
let Vec_ExpandRcd = (
    record as record,
    name as nullable text,
    comboSep as text,
    propSep as text,
    propBase as number
) as list =>
    Vec_ExpandVec(Vec_FromRecord(record), name, comboSep, propSep, propBase)
in
    Vec_ExpandRcd


// Append (flat) vectors by value and by name.
let Vec_Append = (vectors as list) as list =>
    if List.AnyTrue(List.Transform(vectors, Vec_HasNames)) then
        Vec_FromList(
            List.Combine(vectors),
            List.Combine(List.Transform(vectors, Vec_FullNames))
        )
        
    else
        Vec_FromList(List.Combine(vectors), null)
in
    Vec_Append


// Extract names for the whole vector, filled by "missing" where needed.
let Vec_FullNames = (vector as list) as list =>
    if Vec_HasNames(vector) then
        Names_Fill(Vec_Names(vector), List.Count(vector))
    else
        Names_Fill({}, List.Count(vector))
in
    Vec_FullNames


// "Percolate" a name through the names of a vector.
let Vec_PercNames = (
    vector as list,
    name as nullable text,
    comboSep as text,
    propSep as text,
    propBase as number
) as list =>
    if name = null then
        vector
    else Vec_SetNames(
        vector,
        Names_Perc(name, Vec_FullNames(vector), comboSep, propSep, propBase)
    )
in
    Vec_PercNames


// ###################
// ## Miscellaneous ##
// ###################

// "Pad" a list to a certain length.
let List_PadEnd = (
    list as list,
    count as number,
    optional item as any
) as list =>
    let
        length = List.Count(list),
        pad = List.Max({0, count - length}),
        result = if pad > 0 then
            List.Combine({list, List.Repeat({item}, pad)})
        else
            list
    in
        result
in
    List_PadEnd


// Overwrite a single field in the metadata.
let Value_PokeMetadata = (
    value as any,
    edit as record
) as any =>
    Value.ReplaceMetadata(value, Record.Combine({
        Value.Metadata(value),
        edit
    }))
in
    Value_PokeMetadata


// Default when NULL.
let Value_IfNull = (
    value as any,
    default as any
) as any =>
    if value = null then
        default
    else
        value
in
    Value_IfNull


// Check if a value is (true) scalar.
let Value_IsScalar = (value as any) as logical =>
    let
        // Constants.
        SCALAR_TYPES = {
            // type null,
            type logical,
            type number,
            type time,
            type date,
            type datetime,
            type datetimezone,
            type duration,
            type text
            // type binary,
            // type type,
            // type list,
            // type record,
            // type table,
            // type function,
            // type anynonnull,
            // type none
        },
        
        // Workflow.
        result = if value = null then
            true
        else
            List.Contains(SCALAR_TYPES, Value.Type(value))
    in
        result
in
    Value_IsScalar
```